# Laravel autocomplete 404 (Not Found)

Tags: php, laravel, autocomplete, http-status-code-404

So i am noob working with laravel, i have try find a solution but i can not find out.

I am making a autocomplete in laravel.

My route:

```
 Route::get('autocomplete',array('as'=>'autocomplete','uses'=>'SearchController@autocomplete'));
```

My SearchController:

```
  public function autocomplete(Request $request)
{
    $data = Country::select("name")->where("name","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%")->get();
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

My script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var path = "{{ route('autocomplete') }}";
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
    source:  function (query, process) {
    return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (data) {
            return process(data);
        });
    }
});
```

And finaly my input:

```
 input class="typeahead form-control" id="front-item-field" placeholder="{{trans('messages.home.where_want_to_go')}}" name="item" type="text" required>
```

The error:

GET http://xxxxx.com/autocomplete?query=p 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Do you have URL rewriting enabled and setup correctly?

Comment: yes i am enable rewiting

Comment: Maybe the `'as'=>'...'` item in the route - I don't think it would but since you're giving the route the same name as its actual URI would a recursion issue be occurring? Otherwise possibly trying to call the route in JavaScript, I haven't used Laravel for a while but to my knowledge you can't do that out of the box? What happens if you `alert(path);` after it?

Comment: i have done the alert(path); and gives the correct xxx.com/autocomplete

Comment: check if the `autocomplete` route is showing in route list by running `php artisan r:l`

Comment: add / in your route

Comment: where i add the "/" ?

Comment: i have run the php artisan r:l and the autocomplete is listed  users,locale                            |
|        | GET|HEAD      | autocomplete                               | autocomplete | App\Http\Controllers\SearchController@autocomplete                 | web

Comment: i think the proble is that the script can't acess to the SearchController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i have made a mistake the route was inside of a route group for auth user, so i have change the line of the route to evry one can see and works like a charm.